# How do I show an arrow just to the selected item?JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this example:

https://jsfiddle.net/6yg8ckno/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="patrat1 inline">
    <p class="menu1"><img class="sageata" src="http://paul.dac-proiect.ro/wp-content/themes/wpbootstrap/images/logo-arrow.png">MENU1</p>
    <p class="menu1"><img class="sageata" src="http://paul.dac-proiect.ro/wp-content/themes/wpbootstrap/images/logo-arrow.png">MENU2</p>
    <p class="menu1"><img class="sageata" src="http://paul.dac-proiect.ro/wp-content/themes/wpbootstrap/images/logo-arrow.png">MENU3</p>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.patrat2 .content2').hide();
    $('.patrat1 p img').hide();
    $('.patrat1 p:first-child img').show();

    $('.patrat1 p').click(function() {
        var clicked = $(this);
        $('.patrat1 p img').show();
        $('.patrat1 p:first-child img').hide();
    });
});
```

I want that when the user clicks on an item, arrow to display and hide the rest.
Unfortunately my example is incomplete and I'm stuck at this point.

Can you give me some suggestions on how you should proceed?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can hide the image using css, after that you can show it with jQuery when its clicked using `show()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `this`:

```
$('.patrat1').on('click', 'p', function () {
    $('.sageata').hide();
    $(this).find('.sageata').show();
});
```

`$(this)` inside the event handler is the `p` element that was clicked.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/6yg8ckno/1/

Comment: Yes,Works perfecty...but how can display the items in the line? look at image http://i59.tinypic.com/kba8ue.jpg.I think everything should be done not with jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, hide all `.sageata` without exception, then you show `.sageata` into clicked `p` element. And that's all! :)

```
 $('.patrat1 p').click(function(){
      $(".sageata").hide();
      $('.sageata', this).show();
  });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6yg8ckno/3/